# Field [field] not present as part of path [field.query] for Elasticsearch ingest pipeline

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-8

I'm creating an ingest pipeline in Elasticsearch with a gsub processor and I keep getting this error when testing the pipeline on a document. I had to add a unique delimiter before ingesting to deal with a whitespace issue. I'm now trying to replace that delimiter with white spaces. The delimiter is |x| and my configuration for the gsub processor is `^\\|x\\|$`. I would use "ignore_failure" but then the processor will never truly work if it can't find the field I'm trying to modify.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting simply means that the processor cannot find the field you want it to replace. Since there is nothing to replace in this case and you expect some field not to have this field, you can simply suppress the error by adding "ignore_missing" to the processor:

```
POST /_ingest/pipeline/_simulate
{
  "pipeline" :
  {
    "description": "_description",
    "processors": [
      {
        "gsub": {
          "field" : "field.query",
          "pattern": "\\|x\\|",
          "replacement": " ",
          "ignore_missing": true
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "docs": [
    {
      "_index": "index",
      "_id": "id",
      "_source": {
        "field": {
          "query": "foo|x|bar"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "_index": "index",
      "_id": "id",
      "_source": {
        "field": {
          "query": "foo|x|bar and foo|x|baz"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "_index": "index",
      "_id": "id",
      "_source": {
        "no_field": "foobar"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. I tried out ignore_missing and it ran through the pipeline but unfortunately the query field was shorted to only the characters before the first |x| delimiter. I was hoping this it would replace all |x| with a whitespace.

Comment: That's because your regex is incorrect. It expects `|x|` to be the entire line. The `^` requires regex to match the start of the string and `$` matches the end. If you will remove both it will match `|x|` anywhere in the string. I have updated the example.

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice the corrected regex in your code. One last question, my pipeline is technically able to run when turning on ignore_missing, but it thinks that the field is missing from ALL documents, even when it's present. Therefore, the pipeline is ineffective. Any guesses as to why?

Comment: Can you show how your document looks like?